# How can I display a quiver plot between two cross-correlated images?

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I have written a code in MATLAB which allows me to automatically crop regions of interest in one image, and perform cross-correlation with a second image. The correlated regions are identified by a quiver plot, which I would like to extend across the two images (they are arranged in a vertical montage). However, the quiver arrows appear only in the upper image. 
Would anyone know why this happens (and how to fix it)? Hopefully it's something straightforward. I've included some of my code below. Thanks!

```
Initial = rgb2gray(imread('img9.png'));
Secondary = rgb2gray(imread('img8.png'));
XC = imcrop(Initial, [0 0 1300 350]);
YC = imcrop(Secondary, [0 0 1300 350]);
Multi = cat(1,XC,YC);
VertLinSpace1 = linspace(0, 300, 7);
HorzLinSpace1 = linspace(0, 1250, 24);
imshow(Multi)
axis( [0  1300   0  700])
axis on
for k1 = 1:length(VertLinSpace1)
    for k2 = 1:length(HorzLinSpace1)
        template = imcrop(Multi, [HorzLinSpace1(k2)  VertLinSpace1(k1), 50  50]);
        c = normxcorr2(template,YC);
        [ypeak, xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));
        yO = ypeak-size(template,1);
        xO = xpeak-size(template,2);
        x1 = HorzLinSpace1(k2); y1 = VertLinSpace1(k1); x2 = xO+1; y2 = yO+1;
        a = [x1, y1, 0];
        b = [x2, y2, 0];
        Q = [x1 y1
            x2 y2];
        QX = Q(:,1);
        QY = Q(:,2);
        [~,UV] = gradient(Q);
        UVX = [UV(1,1); 0];
        UVY = [UV(1,2); 0];
        figure(1)
        hold on
        quiver(QX, QY, UVX, UVY, 'color','red')
        hold off
    end
end
```

[Initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fTa1.png)
[Comparison image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg1co.png)

Comment: did you lookup image registration examples, such as this one? https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/use-phase-correlation-as-preprocessing-step-in-registration.html

Comment: Hi Yuval, I have looked at that and I'm afraid it doesn't really work for my application - I need to know the magnitude and angle of each "change" between the two images. A quiver plot allows me to do this. All I would like to do is show the quiver arrows between the two images, instead of just on one image.

Comment: Since your images are not available it is hard to tell, but I would check the ranges of UVX and UVY. if they are too small you may get arrows you cannot see

Comment: Hi Yuval, I have added links to the two images I am using at the end of my post. I have checked the ranges of UVX and UVY as you suggested. UVX and UVY are part of the gradient generated by matrix Q, the co-ordinates of which are limited by the linspace variables (in particular VertLinSpace). However, extending VertLinSpace does not solve the issue. I'm quite new to MATLAB, so any further help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your maximum y value (QY) is 349, so no arrow can start at the bottom half of the 700 pix hight image

Comment: Yes you are right. Any idea how I could fix this? Possibly some suggested code? I have tried altering both LinSpace variables, as well as creating additional for loops, but neither of these work.

Comment: what are the arrows supposed to mean?

Comment: I am using the arrows to indicate a difference between regions. The code I have written takes a 50x50 region from one image, and finds the most similar region in the second image. The arrows indicate the point from which the cropped region was taken (first image), to the point that was matched (the second image). This is why I would like the arrows to extend over both images, so this process can be shown more clearly. I have used a Quiver plot as it allows me to show the magnitude and angle of each arrow (i.e. how one region has moved in relation to the other). Hope this clears things up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the arrow XY computation, but the essence was to add 350 to point down to the second half. I added 25 to indicate the middle of the template (the tail of the arrows). This may not be 100% accurate solution, because, for example, the middle of a 50 by 50 pixel square is 25.5 (25 pixels on either side) but it solves the main issue and you can take it from here.

```
Initial = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fTa1.png'));
Secondary = rgb2gray(imread(('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg1co.png')));
XC = imcrop(Initial, [0 0 1300 350]);
YC = imcrop(Secondary, [0 0 1300 350]);
Multi = cat(1,XC,YC);
VertLinSpace1 = linspace(0, 300, 7);
HorzLinSpace1 = linspace(0, 1250, 24);
imshow(Multi)
axis( [0  1300   0  700])
axis on
hold on
counter = 0;
for kV = 1:length(VertLinSpace1)
    for kH = 1:length(HorzLinSpace1)
        template = imcrop(Multi, [HorzLinSpace1(kH)  VertLinSpace1(kV), 50  50]);
        c = normxcorr2(template,YC);
        [ypeak, xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));
        fromXY = [HorzLinSpace1(kH)+25,VertLinSpace1(kV)+25];
        addXY = [xpeak-fromXY(1),350+ypeak-fromXY(2)];
        quiver(fromXY(1), fromXY(2), addXY(1), addXY(2), 'color','red')
        drawnow
    end
end
```

Comment: Yuval, you are awesome. That works well enough for me - I'll make any extra changes on my end. Thank you so much!